# Bluez-A2DP as sink

Tags: bluetooth

I want to configure and use Bluez as an audio sink for my Android Based Car Head Unit, so that I can connect a smart phone to the Car Head Unit.

The smart phone must work as a source of audio stream and head unit must work as an audio sink, so that when I stream from my Phone I should be able to listen to songs on the car speakers.

The car head unit is android-2.1 and uses Bluez -  4.47.

Has anybody already achieved this. If yes, please let me know what extra modules/application is required apart from Bluez to achieve the same on the Car Head Unit.

Comment: if I can ask, what head unit do you have and where did you get it? I have been looking for a true 2 DIN, head unit, that runs android, and also has the "normal head unit" features, like CD/DVD, AM/FM tuner, RDS, etc

Comment: @Ryan : The Head Unit is a development sample and is specific/customized to Nissan car. Still not released in the market.